# Why do we need to use a stringstream when splitting a string?

Tags: c++, types, stream, c++17

Please note, I've never used streams before today, so my understanding of them remains rather vague. Apologies when I say something appallingly stupid.

Here I have a short bit of code that splits up a stringstream into a bunch of strings at each space.

```cpp
vector<string> words;
stringstream ss("some random words that I wrote just now");
string word;
while(getline(ss, word, ' ')){
    words.push_back(word);
}
```

I'm wondering why we're using a `stringstream` here, rather than just a `string`.
This would work like:

1. Create a string object at memory location x
2. When referenced, go through each character and check if it is a space. All previous characters should be saved somewhere temporary.
3. If it is a space, grab all the stuff we've just stored and stick it on the end of the vector, then, clear the temp storage thing. If it's not a space, go back to step 2

What's storing `"some random words that I wrote just now"` as a `stringstream` going to do to help us here?
Is it just making a stream of characters so that we can check through them? Is this necessary? Are we always doing this, even in other languages?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You're using a stringstream because that's how you choose to do the string splitting. You could use some other method to do string splitting, but that's the one you picked.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all the downvotes. The question's clear; the answer's correct.

Comment: @OP -- The code using `std::stringstream` works correctly.  Your `2)` and `3)` -- does it work?  Does it have bugs?  Are there corner cases that were not realized?  That's why `std::stringstream` is used -- the less code you write, the less chance of bugs to occur.  In a real-life C++ code review, if the purpose of the code is to grab each string separated by white-space, and you show one that doesn't use `stringstream` and instead does your 1), 2), and 3), don't be shocked if the code is rejected, regardless if it works (or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's storing `"some random words that I wrote just now"` as a `stringstream` going to do to help us here? Is it just making a stream of characters so that we can check through them? Is this necessary?

`std::stringstream` just allows you to use the usual input/output operations such as `>>` and `std::getline` on a string. You can't use `std::getline` to read from an `std::string`, so you put the string in a `std::streamstream` first. You can totally parse a string by looping over the characters yourself as you described.

> Are we always doing this, even in other languages?

Not in Python at least. There you would just do `words = line.split(' ')`.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering why we're using a stringstream here, rather than just a string.

If this is the question, then one big reason why `stringstream` is used is simply -- because it works with little effort by the programmer.  The less code you write, the less chance for bugs to occur.

Your method of using just `std::string` and searching for spaces requires the C++ programmer to write all of those steps (create a string, manually search for spaces, etc).  It may be trivial to write, but even the best programmers can make mistakes in trivial code.  The code may have bugs, may not cover all of the corner cases, etc.

As to ease of use:

When a C++ programmer sees `stringstream` with respect to usage of separating a sting with whitespace, the purpose of the code is immediately known.

If on the other hand, a programmer decides to manually parse the data by using just `string` and searching for spaces, the code is not immediately realized as to what it does when another programmer reads the code.  Sure, it may be a quick realization of the code by the other programmer, but I can bet the other programmer will say "why didn't you use stringstream?".